# HTML button onclick function not recognised in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I have an HTML file linked to a script. A button defined in the HTML has an onclick function 'incrementLabel()' but the function in the script throws the warning:

> 'incrementLabel' is declared but its value is never read.

```js
function incrementLabel() {

    var text = document.getElementById("testLabel").textContent;
    document.getElementById("testLabel").innerText = (parseInt(text) + 1);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="js/Main.js"></script>

        <title>Test Web App</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="incrementLabel()">Test</button>
        <label id="testLabel">0</label>
    </body>

</html>
```

I can't find any solutions to the problem other than writing the function in a  in HTML. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo: incrementLtabel() » incrementLabel()

Comment: Oops, that must've been from me messing around trying different things. Changed it but the problem still persists.

Comment: What problem are you having? I just tried your code and it works fine for me without error.

Comment: Oh, strange. The problem I'm having is basically the button just does nothing. It doesn't recognise the onclick function.

Comment: I'm running it on a live server using the visual studio code extension. I don't know if that changes anything?

Comment: It's working fine in JSFiddle.

Comment: You may need to update your VSCode if you haven't as it was displaying errors for onclick events in a previous version. You should also consider using a click eventlistener instead of onclick: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>
function incrementLabel() {

    var text = document.getElementById("testLabel").textContent;
    document.getElementById("testLabel").innerText = (parseInt(text) + 1);

}
</script>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="js/Main.js"></script>

        <title>Test Web App</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="incrementLabel()">Test</button>
        <label id="testLabel">0</label>
    </body>

</html>
```

This works perfectly fine. Check if you are importing your JS script correctly.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can put the javascript code into a   before the closing tag .

   HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="js/Main.js"></script>

    <title>Test Web App</title>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="incrementLabel()">Test</button>
    <label id="testLabel">0</label>

<script>
    function incrementLabel() {

    var text = document.getElementById("testLabel").textContent;
    document.getElementById("testLabel").innerText = (parseInt(text) + 1);

    }
</script>
</body>
```

2. Some of online tools like https://playcode.io don't recognise your code but I have tested in vscode and works fine.
3. Maybe have to use other online tool or can test if you have imported the code well with a console.log("Works fine") into your javascript file.

Sorry for my english.